# How do I add the "YouTube Data API v3" API meta-data on manifest?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, youtube-data-api

I been looking on internet some code that shows how to add the YouTube Data API v3 API meta-data code on the manifest, but no succeed.

It is just something like this?

```
<meta-data android:value="My_API_KEY"/>
```

or do I have to add more things?

Will appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup), it is all done via code. Something like

```
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR_KEY_HERE";
private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubeFragment;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener listener;
...

public void init() {
  youTubeFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, listener);
}
```

I strongly suggest you to take a look at the [official sample applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), there's everything you need to know.